# Hex grid in ncurses

Tags: python, c++, ncurses, python-curses

I'm looking to write a roguelike game which uses hexagonal tiles rather than square ones. (A hex is equidistant from all its neighbors.) Is there a way to arrange this in ncurses? Really, it's only necessary to offset every odd-numbered line in a pad by 1/2 of a character's width.

I prefer python, but I know c++ also. Tagged this question as both in case the latter is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get close to it.

```
 __    __    __    __
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__/
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__/
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__/
```

Terminal cells tend to be close to 2/1 ratio; by multiplying `X` by 4, `Y` by 2 and shifting every other line by two characters you get close enough to an hexagonal grid.

```
x   x   x   x   x   x   x

  x   x   x   x   x   x
           \ /
x   x   x --x-- x   x   x
           / \
  x   x   x   x   x   x

x   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

You can also build a finer grid with

```
x x x x x x x x x x x x x
 x x x x x o o x x x x x
x x x x x o + o x x x x x
 x x x x x o o x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

i.e. double `X` and shift every other line by one space.

In code (Python):

```
def screen_pos(i, j):
    return i*2 + (j & 1), j

def neighbors(i, j):
    h = 1 - (j & 1)
    return [(i-1, j), (i+1, j),
            (i-h, j-1), (i-h, j+1),
            (i-h+1, j-1), (i-h+1, j+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at rhex: https://github.com/dpc/rhex , it is in Rust, but should give you a basic idea how it could work. It uses a hex2d-rs library.